# iframe height adjust not working

Tags: javascript

I have an iframe with an button that when clicked expands a list.   I want the height of that iframe to adjust once the button is clicked.  Here is the code I have in the iframe:

```
     <script>
$(function() {
    $("#field12593102_1").click(function() {
        window.parent.adjustIFrameHeight();
    });
});
</script>
```

The code in the parent frame is the following:

```
    function adjustIFrameHeight(){
$('.childframe').css('height', function(index) {
  return index +=400;});
};
```

I know that the parent frame code works because I have tried it without a call to the function but it does not work as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the 2nd argument of the function called by css()

```
function adjustIFrameHeight(){
$('.childframe').css('height', function(index,value) {
  return value + 400;});
};
```

The 1st argument is the index of the current element inside the jQuery-object, not the current property(width in this case).

You may also use:

```
function adjustIFrameHeight(){
    $('.childframe').css('height', '+=400');
    };
```

Comment: This cannot work when iframe and parent document are placed on different domains, it's restricted by same-origin-policy

Comment: @zach: that is a cross-domain iframe. You can't script across domains due to the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
function adjustIFrameHeight(){
$('.childframe').css('height', function(index) {
  return index +=400;});
};
```

to:

```
function adjustIFrameHeight(){
    $('.childframe').css({height: function(index, value) {
      return value +=400;}
    });
};
```