# Dynamic iframe height

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, iframe

I have a problem. I'm working on a template which is composed by a central div and an iframe inside it. The div should resize dynamically depending on the content of the iframe. I tried other solutions found here, without results. 
I'm using the following HTML code:

```
<div id="site_content" style="position:relative; width:445px; height:500px;">

    <iframe id="mainframe" name="mainframe" onload="parent.adjustIFrameHeight();" FRAMEBORDER="0" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;" src="http://www.letsapp.it/alecianetti/" width="445" height="600"></iframe>

</div>
```

I would like the div (#site_content) resize dynamically on iframe content change. I tried this function but I'm not very expert in using js and similar (I'm studying them now ;)) so I don't know if it's useful or correct

```
onload="parent.adjustIFrameHeight();"
```

To give you an idea of the result, I link you a demo site of [ThemeForest Wave CV](http://themeforest.net/item/wave-cv-first-impression/full_screen_preview/300441) which is the template I'm replicating.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have a look at this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671275/iframe-height-adjust-not-working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671275/iframe-height-adjust-not-working

Comment: Hi Phillip and thank you for the answer. However it doesn't work at all. Other suggestions ?

Comment: Note for all: for modern browsers, they will have security check on cross-domain issues. make sure you define same value of `document.domain` in JavaScript to remove the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it out!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setIframeHeight(iframeName) {
          //var iframeWin = window.frames[iframeName];
          var iframeEl = document.getElementById? document.getElementById(iframeName): document.all? document.all[iframeName]: null;
          if (iframeEl) {
          iframeEl.style.height = "auto"; // helps resize (for some) if new doc shorter than previous
          //var docHt = getDocHeight(iframeWin.document);
          // need to add to height to be sure it will all show
          var h = alertSize();
          var new_h = (h-148);
          iframeEl.style.height = new_h + "px";
          //alertSize();
          }
        }

        function alertSize() {
          var myHeight = 0;
          if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
            //Non-IE
            myHeight = window.innerHeight;
          } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
            //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
            myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
          } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
            //IE 4 compatible
            myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
          }
          //window.alert( 'Height = ' + myHeight );
          return myHeight;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="setIframeHeight('ifr');">
<center>
    <iframe id="ifr" src="yourdomain!" onload="parent.adjustIFrameHeight();" width="850px" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Philipp. I've got this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'adjustIFrameHeight'

Comment: Sorry, I got the same error. But the script basically works?!

Comment: Yes, I've changed "parent.adjustIFrameHeight();" with "parent.setIFrameHeight();" and it works well. The problem is that now the height is fixed to the taller div (it's fixed to 800px).

Comment: I did delete it but nothing happened. Now the height is fixed to the max height div. What can I do now ?

Comment: @PhilippBraun Please note that [begging for votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes) is generally not encouraged by the community